# Using keyworded args in a function for MongoDB projection

Tags: python, mongodb, keyword-argument

I want to write a flexible function for my Mongo DB that allows me to pass in any number of keys to search for in a collection and return the count of documents.  So far I have:

```
def search_db(**kwargs):

    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        return Mdb['collection1'].find({}, {kwargs[k]:1})
```

This only allows me to search for one get at a time and iterating over the kwargs kind of defeats the purpose of creating a projection.  How can I make it so I can search multiple keys at once?

Comment: What's the dot doing in `Mdb.['collection1']`?

Comment: edited for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `*args`

I do not really get why you use `**kwargs` here and only use the values, whereas you can use `*args`:

```
def search_db(*args):
    return Mdb['collection1'].find({}, {arg: True for arg in args})
```

This will thus make a projection with all the arguments you give to `search_db`, like:

```
search_db('field1','field2')
```

## Using `**kwargs`

If you really want to use `**kwargs`, then you can use for example:

```
def search_db(**kwargs):
    return Mdb['collection1'].find({}, {arg: True for arg in kwargs.values()})
```

and call it with:

```
search_db(foo='field1',bar='field2')
```

But here `foo` and `bar` as names (not the values), are simply ignored.

You can use `{arg: True for arg in kwargs}` if you want to process the parameter names instead.

Comment: the `{arg:1 for arg in kwargs} ` was exactly what I wanted to do.  And I needed to use kwargs because I created subsets of the keys in the collection and want all keys associated with that subset to be passed into the function under a specific keyword.  thanks!

Comment: @e9e9s: I made a typo. If you only want to take the values into account, it should be a `for arg in kwargs.values()`. (or you can use `in kwargs` if you want to use the keys (parameter names).